# QListWidgetItem with Radio Button

Tags: c++, qt, qt4.8

I'm working on my first QT application and I have a problem with `QListWidgetItems`.

I will be having different kind of list. 
for checkboxed list using:

```
listElement[i]->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEnabled);

listElement[i]->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
```

works exactly as wanted.

But now I want a Radio Button list. so my question is in two parts

1. can use the same logic that I used for checkBox to create Radio Buttons?
2. I have used:

   ```
   listElement[i]->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEnabled);

   QRadioButton *radio1 = new QRadioButton(0);

   dlList->setItemWidget(listElement[i],radio1);
   ```

this will display Items in the list with a radio Button, the problem is that the text is Over the Radio Button:

going to try to demonstrate without image

> This is a test
>   o
>   for elements 1

instead for checkbox I have

> ```
>    This is a test
> ```
>
> []
>
> ```
>    for element 1
> ```

how can I get the radioButton to align correctly with text?

**New Questions:**

Thanks alot for the answers my text is next to my RadioButton now.

Only thing there is no WordWrap, My text is Longer than maximum Size of the RadioButton. How can I get it to wordwrap:

```
rButton = new QRadioButton();

rButton->setFixedSize(LIST_TEXT_WIDTH_WO_ICON, LIST_TEXT_HEIGHT);

rButton->setStyleSheet("border:none");

rButton->setFont(segoe18Font);

rButton->setText("This is just a test for elementsss of type euh!!!");

rButton->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Preferred);

dropListWidget->setItemWidget(listElement, rButton);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you may have read, there are two approaches to achieve what you want.

1. The most flexible one: use a `QListView`, implement a new delegate and a model if necessary.
2. Keep using the classic item-based interface (`QListWidget`) and change the item's widgets either by sub-classing `QListWidgetItem` or calling `QListWidgetItem::setItemWidget`.

Since the question points towards the second one, I'll try to provide the simplest item-based solution.

The following piece of code generates the list widget in the picture.

[image]

```
QListWidgetItem *it;

it = new QListWidgetItem(ui->listWidget);
ui->listWidget->setItemWidget(it, new QRadioButton(tr("Item 1")));

it = new QListWidgetItem(ui->listWidget);
ui->listWidget->setItemWidget(it, new QRadioButton(tr("Item 2")));

// .
// .
// .

it = new QListWidgetItem(ui->listWidget);
ui->listWidget->setItemWidget(it, new QRadioButton(tr("Item N")));
```

where `ui->listWidget` is a pointer to the `QListWidget` that holds the items.

I hope this helps. As far as I understand, that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks, it works, I have added a second part to the original question